# How to upload multiple file in one form

Tags: laravel

[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D83Di.png)

I have a few file upload, then how to upload all the file only for input that have files.
DO i need to upload one by one or push all in one array, then save the data using the array.

any suggestion ?

Comment: you can't multi upload at once, my suggestion upload one by one inside loop

Comment: What is the problem in uploading in once, You can just put all the files in an array and upload them to the server, In the server, you can simply validate them and iterate over all of them and copy them to your FileServer